# how to send and receive a tcp message to a specific IP/Port in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, tcpclient

I'm trying to send a message to a specific IP/Port and receive a reply in an ASP.net website, i tried the method describd at the following link but it didn't work for me as you can see :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022407/socketexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its

is there any ideas to solve this problem,or any other ways to achieve this

Thank you very much , i really appreciate your help

Comment: You should enhance the original post instead of creating a new one to refer to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SocketException An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022407/socketexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its)

Comment: "sending a message to a TCP port" and "receive a reply in an ASP.net website" are both pretty vague. And is that port on the IIS server?

Comment: It's the same IP for the webserver, I've a plugin installed on it and listening to the port 6000 also i have an ASP.net website working on its IIS, on the website I've a form to send the tcp request to the plugin (127.0.0.1:6000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) or [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) classes.

The first one is simpler and basically is a wrapper around the second one.

You probably just need [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx). It is even simpler, if it meets your needs of course.